# #define in precompiled header not recognized in .mm files

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, ios

Why would a #define statement in a .pch not be recognized by .mm files?

Results in "use of undeclared identifier" and "not declared in this scope" when attempting to reference the macro.

Pch looks like this:

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iPhone SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dNSLog(...) NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
#else
#define dNSLog(format, ...)
#endif
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste the contents of your .pch file?

Comment: At first sight, your prefix header looks okay. I’d put that `#ifdef DEBUG` inside `#ifdef __OBJC__` since you use `NSString`, though. I assume `dNSLog()` is the macro that’s giving you errors. Are you able to check the preprocessor output of the offending .mm file and see whether the prefix header has been used? Also, is the offending .mm file correctly added to the target that uses your prefix header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, cleaning was not solving it.

After closing and restarting Xcode 4 everything was fine.
If that can help someone...

Comment: That was exactly the solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Xcode 4 wasn't actually cleaning the build. :(